# Domain of $f(x) = \log_{x + 0.5} {|x^2 - 5x + 6|}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

> Find maximum possible domain of $$f(x) = \log_{(x + 0.5)} {|x^2 - 5x + 6|}$$

Hello,

I am solving the above problem.

Here is my work:

$$x + 0.5 > 0, x \neq 0.5$$
$$x > -0.5, x \neq 0.5$$

Now, $$|x^2 - 5x + 6|$$ will always be positive except when it's $0$. So, $$x \neq 2, 3$$

Hence, answer = $$(-0.5, 0.5) \cup (0.5, 2) \cup (2, 3) \cup (3, \infty)$$

Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it's correct. Besides, you can also write it as $(-0.5,∞)-\text{{-0.5,2,3}}$

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai Thanks

Comment: Yes it is correct.

Comment: @NandeeshBhatrai do you mean $(-0.5,\infty)-\{0.5,2,3\}$?

Comment: @BenjaminWang oh yes. Thanks.

Comment: [Hii, please do not use signature, taglines, greetings, thanks, or other chitchat in your post.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17207/983440)